# Write ASCII values of a string to a file C

Tags: c, file-io

So I am trying to get the ASCII values of characters in a string, then write that array of ASCII values to a file. At the same time, I want the format of the output to be something like this: `"Hello\n"` is output to file in the format `72 101 108 108 111\n` instead of

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

Which is what I have right now.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
   int out = open("tmp.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600);
   if (-1 == out) {
      perror("opening tmp.txt");
      exit(1);
   }

   if (-1 == dup2(out, fileno(stdout))) {
      perror("cannot redirect stdout");
      exit(1);
   }

   char buff[128];

   strcpy(buff, "Hello\n");

   int n = 0;
   while(buff[n] != '\n') {
      fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", (int)buff[n]);
      n++;
   }

   fflush(stdout);
   close(out);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: the `\n` in the fprintf is the problem. Also, you should be using `fopen` and `fclose`.

Comment: Oh right I was thinking about something else much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\n` from the `fprintf` and add a `\n` after the while loop:

```
while(buff[n] != '\n') {
  fprintf(out, "%d ", (int)buff[n]);
  n++;
}
fprintf(out, "\n");
```